# Drupal/Ubercart payment notification path?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

What's the path on which Drupal / Ubercart usually receives the successful payment notifications from 3rd party websites ?

I need to provide a path for the notifications to the payment server. Since this is not specified in the documentation, I was wondering if there is a usual one in Ubercart.

(I'm using AlertPay if it can help)

Hope it is clear.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the completion URL is http://www.example.com/alertpay/complete and the cancel URL is http://www.example.com/alpertpay/cancel. They are specified in the [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) implementation in the [.module file](http://www.blisstering.com/alert-pay-integration-drupal). In this case, look for the uc_alertpay_menu function.